# CSS3 ::Before on hover

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have an element that toggles between different a `font awesome` icons on click. I would like this effect on hover too. But it doesn't seem to work as I'd expect.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1718/

Works Fine

```
#heart-btn span.hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}
```

Doesn't work

```
#heart-btn:hover span.hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}
```

Doesn't work

```
#heart-btn span.hearted:hover::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class name (`.not-hearted`) instead of only `<span>`. Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$("#heart-btn span").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('not-hearted hearted');
});
```

```css
#heart-btn span.hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}

#heart-btn:hover > .not-hearted:before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}

#heart-btn span.not-hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f08a';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="heart-btn">
  <span class="fa not-hearted"></span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - as this example was a simplified version it didn't work, so i had to remove the `>` from `#heart-btn:hover > .not-hearted:before {` and it now works.

Comment: Its my pleasure @steve

Answer (score 2):

Add this css to your css file

```
#heart-btn span.not-hearted:hover:before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1720/

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order of your css.

```js
$("#heart-btn span").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('not-hearted hearted');
});
```

```css
#heart-btn span.hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}

#heart-btn span.not-hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f08a';
}

#heart-btn:hover > span::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="heart-btn">
  <span class="fa not-hearted"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to do it with your jQuery code you can chain to your selector and use the `hover` method.

```
$("#heart-btn span").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('not-hearted hearted');
}).hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('not-hearted hearted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `#heart-btn:hover > span::before` to `#heart-btn:hover > span.not-hearted::before`

```js
$("#heart-btn span").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('not-hearted hearted');
});
```

```css
#heart-btn span.hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}

#heart-btn:hover > span.not-hearted::before {
  color: green;
  content: '\f004';
}

#heart-btn span.not-hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f08a';
}
#heart-btn:hover span.hearted::before {
  color: black;
  content: '\f004';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="heart-btn">
  <span class="fa not-hearted"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the correct structure :) No javascript is needed here.

(I gave you two examples - the first one is for `hover` on the div, the second is for hover on the span).

```css
#heart-btn1 span.hearted::before, #heart-btn2 span.hearted::before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f004';
}

#heart-btn1:hover > span:before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f08a';
}
#heart-btn2 > span:hover:before {
  color: #c71616;
  content: '\f08a';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="heart-btn1">
  <span class="fa hearted"></span>
</div>
<div id="heart-btn2">
  <span class="fa hearted"></span>
</div>
```